# Resource not found when calling ActionResult from Controller from multiple submit buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, submit

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

I am following the answer in this link, I have done this...

```
<% Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancel" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>

<% Html.BeginForm("Send", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Send" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>

<% Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Cancel" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

With this in the controller...

```
public class MyController : Controller {
public ActionResult MyAction(string submitButton) {
    switch(submitButton) {
        case "Send":
            // delegate sending to another controller action
            return(Send());
        case "Cancel":
            // call another action to perform the cancellation
            return(Cancel());
        default:
            // If they've submitted the form without a submitButton, 
            // just return the view again.
            return(View());
    }
}

private ActionResult Cancel() {
    // process the cancellation request here.
    return(View("Cancelled"));
}

private ActionResult Send() {
    // perform the actual send operation here.
    return(View("SendConfirmed"));
}
```

}

But I keep getting a Resource not found error - Cannot find MyController\MyAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't specify "Controller" in the Form parameter:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "My", FormMethod.Post); %>
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancel" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Link will be /My/MyAction if you want it to be MyController, the Controller class must be called MyControllerController (not tested though)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ensure you have a route that MVC can match to your Controller/Action. Something like:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "MyRoute",
        "{controller}/{action}/{submitButton}",
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", submitButton = "Default" }
    );
```